# Display arraylist of hash map in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have map which has List as values and Integers as keys.I want to display the values of the list if the key is 0,1 .How is it possible using Struts2 in jsp?

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> parameter_map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
```

```html
<s:iterator value="parameter_map">
  <h3><s:property value="key" /></h3>
  <table>
    <s:iterator value="value">
      <tr><td><s:property /></td></tr>
    </s:iterator>
  </table>
</s:iterator>
```

This is what I tried to do in jsp to display.But nothing is displayed.

Comment: which map? please provide relevant code section

Comment: edit option does not edit code properly.

Comment: Thanks ..I am trying to display the list in the jsp.I know how to display values in hash map<String,String>.No idea of how to display the list values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate over an HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> with Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237223/iterate-over-an-hashmapstring-arrayliststring-with-struts-2)

Comment: Do you have a public getter `getParameter_map` (I think that would be the right name, I *really* wish you'd use normal Java naming parameters to completely avoid an entire class of potential issues)? Have you verified there's actually data in the map? Right now it just looks empty.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes I have getter for the same.

Comment: @Soham Works fine for me w/o modification. Check your assumptions.

Comment: Assumptions? Could you explain? Thank you.I am getting a empty list box.

Comment: Assumptions about data, application flow, etc. The syntax is correct, therefore there is either no data, you're not hitting the JSP you think you are, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [iterator](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/iterator.html) tag.It can do the work for you and will push the List on the top of value stack which you can again iterate over, so in short you need a set of nested iterator.

There are couple of examples out there which can show you how to iterate over the map.

Have a look at following links

- [An advanced example for indexed Lists and Maps](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-AnadvancedexampleforindexedListsandMaps)
- [Iterate over a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` with Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237223/iterate-over-an-hashmapstring-arrayliststring-with-struts-2)

Comment: @Soham Define "does not work." You don't describe the code you're trying, so it's impossible to diagnose. You don't say what goes wrong, so all we can do is guess.

Comment: @Dave I have edited the question.Please take a look at it and let me know whats going wrong.

Comment: @Soham: what you have describe din your code should work and i believe as suggested in comments you need to check if there is data coming in list or not