# Iterating the HashMap in JSP using strut2

Tags: jsp, struts2

```
Iterator<Entry<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>>> 
iter=cellLinesList.entrySet().iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Entry en=iter.next();
        System.out.println("The bay is ................"+en.getKey());
        HashMap<String,List<String>> rowList=(HashMap<String, List<String>>) en.getValue();
        Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> rowIter=rowList.entrySet().iterator();
        while(rowIter.hasNext()){
            Entry rowEn=rowIter.next();
            System.out.println("The row is ..................."+rowEn.getKey());
            List<String> cellsList=(List<String>) rowEn.getValue();
            for(String s:cellsList){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am unable to iterator this type of the Hashmap,Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Traversing these structures is generally *easier* in JSP than in Java, thanks to iterators doing most of the job for you.

For example, <kbd>[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6655296/1654265)</kbd> explains exactly how to iterate the structure:

```
HashMap<String,<ArrayList<String>>>
```

By the way, in some cases the (lack of) design reaches a point where a refactoring is higly suggested.

This:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>>>
```

is quite a nightmare to handle; try creating some objects like described in <kbd>[this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009137/1654265)</kbd>.